# Cannot download ggsurvfit R package, even with make.exe text file

Tags: r, installation, survival-analysis, ggsurvfit

I've spent literally all day trying to download the package ggsurvfit to visualize a Kaplan-Meier survival distribution. I use Rstudio and I have RTools40 (does the file path of RTools40 matter?). I could also use tidycmprsk package but get similar problems. Please please help! You can see everything I've tried below. If you know an alternative way to make this visualization, let me know.

`install.packages("ggsurvfit") install.packages("ggsurvfit", type = "source") library(remotes) remotes::install_github("ddsjoberg/ggsurvfit") library(devtools) devtools::install_github("pharmaverse/ggsurvfit") install.packages("ggsurvfit", type = "source") install.packages("ggsurvfit", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org")`

Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘ggsurvfit’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\CLAHM\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYl9d8e\downloaded_packages’

`library(ggsurvfit)`
#Error in library(ggsurvfit) : there is no package called ‘ggsurvfit’

In response to a former post about this issue, I also tried making a text file containing the following:
PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}/usr/bin;${PATH}"
in the location:
C:\Users\YourUsername\

`Sys.which("make")`

"C:\rtools40\usr\bin\make.exe"

So the text file exists, but still, the package will not install nor load, with the same errors as above.

Here is all the console produces when I try to install:

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’, ‘ggplot2’

There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.6.2              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.4             FALSE
rlang      1.0.2  1.1.3              TRUE
vctrs      0.4.1  0.6.5              TRUE
ggplot2    3.3.5  3.4.4             FALSE

installing the source packages ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘ggsurvfit’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cli_3.6.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 569771 bytes (556 KB)
downloaded 556 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 107656 bytes (105 KB)
downloaded 105 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 763765 bytes (745 KB)
downloaded 745 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vctrs_0.6.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 969066 bytes (946 KB)
downloaded 946 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.4.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3159578 bytes (3.0 MB)
downloaded 3.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggsurvfit_1.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 985358 bytes (962 KB)
downloaded 962 KB

- installing *source* package 'cli' ...
  ** package 'cli' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
- removing 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/cli'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/cli'
  Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK-cli\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll to C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\cli\libs\x64\cli.dll: Permission denied
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'rlang' ...
  ** package 'rlang' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
- removing 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rlang'
  Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK-rlang\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll to C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rlang\libs\x64\rlang.dll: Permission denied
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'lifecycle' ...
  ** package 'lifecycle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
  Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'lifecycle'
- removing 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/lifecycle'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'vctrs' ...
  ** package 'vctrs' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ERROR: cannot remove earlier installation, is it in use?
- removing 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/vctrs'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/vctrs'
  Warning in file.copy(lp, dirname(pkgdir), recursive = TRUE, copy.date = TRUE) :
  problem copying C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\00LOCK-vctrs\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll to C:\Users\CLAHM\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\vctrs\libs\x64\vctrs.dll: Permission denied
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
  ** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
  namespace 'rlang' 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
  Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
- removing 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
- restoring previous 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggplot2'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
- installing *source* package 'ggsurvfit' ...
  ** package 'ggsurvfit' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** data
  *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
  ** inst
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
  namespace 'ggplot2' 3.3.6 is being loaded, but >= 3.4.0 is required
  Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggsurvfit'
- removing 'C:/Users/CLAHM/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/ggsurvfit'
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggsurvfit’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\CLAHM\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwXs30L\downloaded_packages’

Comment: Installation is failing early when trying to remove previous package versions. Make sure you have the rights to edit files in those folders, and you are installing in a fresh R session without any packages loaded.

Comment: @axeman I tried again with a fresh session, restarted for good measure, I am the only user and open as administrator (it's never told me I don't have permission before), and I even deleted the dependencies I already had installed. Still didn't work. It does always give a pop up like "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?" with options y or n. Now I can't install any packages, even those I had no problems with before? I must be missing something?